# Script para autoclick

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy intentando elaborar un script que haga autoclick en una parte de un iframe.

La idea es la siguiente:

En mi web (web 1) habrá colocado un iframe de otra web (web 2). La idea es que cuando cargue la web1, se haga un autoclick en una parte en concreto del iframe de la web 2.

Hasta el momento, lo único que he encontrado ha sido un código en javascript que hace autoclick, pero sólo en botones, no en iframes.

No sé si esto será posible hacerlo con un código en javascript, que de click por coordenadas.

Answer (score 1):

No se puede acceder al iframe y modificarlo a menos que tengas el codigo de la pagina que estará en iframe y lo que puedes hacer "con su codigo" es una función especifica para lo que estas haciendo, por ejemplo que cuando se cargue la pagina desde un iframe que ejecute esa opción que buscas. Solo tienes que hacer una validación en javascript como la siguiente:

```
function inIframe () {
    try {
        return window.self !== window.top;
    } catch (e) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Si te devuelve true entonces es un iframe y podrás ejecutar lo que necesites.

Answer (score 1):

Si la url cargada en el iframe es del mismo dominio que la página desde la que estás ejecutando el código deberías poder acceder a los elementos del iframe a través de la propiedad `document` del iframe:

```
 window.frames['myIFrame'].document.getElementById('myIFrameElemId')
```

Si, como comentas, el contenido del iframe es de otra web (entiendo que de otro dominio), las políticas de seguridad del navegador no te van a permitir acceder a su contenido.